# react js, how to sequentially / synchronously update states that depend on each other?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state, lets call it B, that I always reset when I change state A.

But: now I want to reset it, and *then* set it again. how to do that with react js?

Example is here:
https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/bGVXxev

the goal is to have "B is 1" in the output

You cannot just remove setB(0) from the useEffect of A

why does this not work? how to make it work, the right way?

Javascript:

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const App = () => {
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  const [B, setB] = useState(0);
  const [msgB, setMsgB] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
      setB(0);
  }, [A]);
  useEffect(()=>{
      setMsgB('B is: ' + B);
  }, [B]);
  const onClick = () =>{
    setA(A ? 0 : 1); //basically a toggle
    setB(1);
  };
  return(
    <div className="box">
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me to test </button>

      <div><strong>A:</strong> {A}</div>
      <div><strong>B:</strong> {B}</div>
      <div>debug:</div>
      <div>{msgB}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

again, what do I want?

I want to call

```
    setA(A ? 0 : 1); //basically a toggle
    setB(1); // <--------- make this work!
```

and have B on value 1. now its *always* 0.

**EDIT**

the initial thought was as well, that those 2 states depend on each other in a non trivial way.

E.g. And imagine that setB(1) depends on A. Just imagine: maybe `setB(A == 1 ? 'one' : 'zero');` which is a trivial example, but imagine a none-trivial example

Comment: Have you considered `useReducer` for A+B state?

Comment: well i read the docs, but I dont see how that would make any difference.

Comment: There would be just one function to update (reducer) the state (A + B). In this function you would have access to both variables and only one re-render/update would be needed.

Comment: same thing. you can refactor the the code to stop using `useEffect` and just call `setA(...); setB(0);` in all occurrences. That is refactoring the entire code, and as I explicitly stated, not what I want. using a reducer wins you absolutely 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `setTimeout` with a delay of `0` to update B separately from the `onClick` handler. This will enqueue that update into a different render cycle as the event queue is processed. All the state updates from the current render cycle will be processed before the update queued in the timeout callback placed at the end of the event queue.

Basically it is because react state updates are asynchronous, but processed in the order in which they are queued up, combined with the fact that a function needs to complete before the effects can be processed. In your code you queue up an "update(A, B1)", but when A is updated it queues an "update(B2)" and overwrites B1. When you use the `setTimeout` it places the "update(B1)" at the end of the event queue, which will be processed after all effects from the render phase are committed.

```
const App = () => {
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  const [B, setB] = useState(0);
  const [msgB, setMsgB] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setB(0);
  }, [A]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMsgB("B is: " + B);
  }, [B]);

  const onClick = () => {
    setA(A ? 0 : 1); //basically a toggle
    // setB(1) // <-- This update is overwritten by the setB(0) from effect A
    setTimeout(setB, 0, 1); // <-- This delays a setB(1) after all effects processed
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me to test </button>

      <div>
        <strong>A:</strong> {A}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>B:</strong> {B}
      </div>
      <div>debug:</div>
      <div>{msgB}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can play with the delay (the second value to `setTimeout`) to something like 500 or 1000 and you'll see the rendered `B` value "blip" 1 then set back to 0, then finally set to 1.

[image: Edit "synchronous" state update]

***EDIT:*** Moving reducer solution here for conversational clarity

> Hooks run once per render cycle. The effect is update A -> reset B. If
>   you then also want another effect, update B -> reset C, it *has* to wait
>   until the next render cycle to pick up the change in B in order to
>   trigger the effect. Each effect like this delays the *actual* change by
>   1 render cycle. This is ok until you try to ***not reset*** state by queuing
>   a set B in the *same* cycle and expect all the later triggered effects
>   to not work as designed.

```
const initialState = {
  A: 0,
  B: 0,
  C: 0
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_A":
      // Reset to { A: value, B: 0, C: 0 }
      return { ...initialState, A: action.value };

    case "SET_B":
      // Keep A, set B, reset C
      return { ...state, B: action.value, C: 0 };

    case "SET_C":
      // Keep A & B, set C
      return { ...state, C: action.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const App = () => {
  const [{ A, B, C }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const [msgB, setMsgB] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setMsgB("B is: " + B);
  }, [B]);

  const onClickA = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_A", value: A ? 0 : 1 });
    dispatch({ type: "SET_B", value: 1 });
    dispatch({ type: "SET_C", value: 3 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <div>
        <strong>A:</strong> {A}
        <button onClick={onClickA}>Toggle A</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>B:</strong> {B}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>C:</strong> {C}
      </div>
      <div>debug:</div>
      <div>{msgB}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit "synchronous" state update with useReducer]

## How/why this works

Because of the delay caused by "reacting" to state updates it is very difficult to reconcile asynchronous updates to be synchronous. The timeout works in the short term, but even just adding a third variable to work with really complicates it.

With a reducer, however, we've control of the entire "set" of variables (*A, B, C, ... Z?*) that need to be reset ***at the same time***. This means we can "collapse" all the state value resets we *know/want* will happen into a single atomic "action" and make the update all in a single render cycle. The benefit of using a reducer function is it ***serializes*** state updates, meaning it processes one action at a time; it runs to completion before the next dispatched action can be processed.

```
dispatch({ type: "SET_A", value: A ? 0 : 1 });
// We know here that state will be { A: <0|1>, B: 0, C: 0 }
dispatch({ type: "SET_B", value: 1 });
// We know here that state will be { A: <0|1>, B: 1, C: 0 }
dispatch({ type: "SET_C", value: 3 });
// We know here that state will be { A: <0|1>, B: 1, C: 3 }
```

Comment: do you have information about that magic? e.g. can you explain, a little worded out, why one worked, and another doesnt? and it feels like a very very weird solution

Comment: @Toskan Apologies, I actually had an error in my original code, I was updating `msgB` directly instead of `B`. I've fixed my answer and tried to provide a better explanation/insight.

Comment: highly appreciate your answer... now one last thing, can you update it to make it work even with a third state C? I did it like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/synchronous-state-update-qtybr?file=/src/App.js i Know it wasnt part of the question. But solving issue AB, next question will always b: and ABC? and it _does_ feel weird to do it this way. Is this really safe to use?

Comment: @Toskan What you did appears to work and do what you want, perhaps suboptimally, but this feels like a suboptimal issue to begin with. The entire concept of an auto-reset state clearly conflicts with normal react state updates. At this point I think the suggestion to switch to a "redux" model (*useReducer*) is ideal. Something where you dispatch actions to update your state, passing an additional action "reset" property for the times when you want to reset state values or not. You'd still have the same issue (race condition) though if using effects to "blindly" reset state.

Comment: I dont see how this is so suboptimal. Seems like a textbook example. Anyway: reducer -> same problem, no?

Comment: @Toskan Same problem, yes, and no. Like I said, if you use an effect to dispatch an action to "reset" some state you'll have the same race condition where the effect runs *after* any queued state updates from the same render cycle. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/synchronous-state-update-with-usereducer-n1pzg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) that instead uses `useReducer` and "reseting" `B` and `C` happen atomically within the reducer.

Comment: so using `useEffect` basically is an anti pattern? because of these exact race conditions? because obviously, when you start out coding "simple problem, simple solution" and all of the sudden you have 300 lines of code in `useEffect`. Is it, or is it not, an anti pattern?

Comment: In a way, yes. Hooks run once per render cycle. The effect is update A -> reset B. If you then also want another effect, update B -> reset C, it *has* to wait until the next render cycle to pick up the change in B in order to trigger the effect. Each effect like this delays the *actual* change by 1 render cycle. This is ok until you try to ***not reset*** state by queuing a set B in the *same* cycle and expect all the later triggered effects to not work as designed. The reducer pattern allows you to "collapse" and control the resetting in a single cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Drews answer works but i'm not sure why you'd do the timeouts in the click handler based on using effects.. effectively and predictably. If what you really want is for B to reset when A changes, then the reset, then eventually update should both be in the effect. I see you question about a third variable above, which i'd expect to have its own effect with its own timeout. It sounds to me that the requirement is that when A changes, B should reset then update to 1. So thats what the effect should do instead of having updates in two different places.

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const App = () => {
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  const [B, setB] = useState(0);
  const [msgB, setMsgB] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
      // When A changes these things should happen
      setB(0);
      setTimeout(setB, 100, 1);
  }, [A]);

  useEffect(()=>{
      // When B changes these things should happen
      setMsgB('B is: ' + B);
  }, [B]);

  const onClick = () =>{
    setA(A ? 0 : 1); //basically a toggle
  };

  return(
    <div className="box">
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me to test </button>

      <div><strong>A:</strong> {A}</div>
      <div><strong>B:</strong> {B}</div>
      <div>debug:</div>
      <div>{msgB}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

For your example with three variables, the same concept applies. If A updates, then X should happen in a useEffect. If B updates then X should happen in a useEffect. This way you know exactly where in the code to expect these types of manipulations

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  const [B, setB] = useState(0);
  const [C, setC] = useState(0);
  const [msgB, setMsgB] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // When A changes these things should happen
    setB(0);
    setTimeout(setB, 100, 1)
  }, [A]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // When B changes these things should happen
    setMsgB("B is: " + B);
    setC(0);
    setTimeout(setC, 100, 1);
  }, [B]);

  const onClick = () => {
    setA(A ? 0 : 1); //basically a toggle
  };

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me to test </button>

      <div>
        <strong>A:</strong> {A}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>B:</strong> {B}
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>C:</strong> {C}
      </div>
      <div>debug:</div>
      <div>{msgB}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```